# media players that supports MPEG-DASH

Tags: media-player, mpeg2-ts, mpeg-dash

I want DASH MPD files to be played and tested on to different DASH supported clients.
I have tested with VLC dash plugin.
Are there any other players/plugins that supports and plays DASH MPD files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One client I have experience of is the Helix SDK for Android, which supports MPEG-DASH. This is a commercially licensed and supported client specifically for retro support on Android 2.2 to Android 4.x devices. Interestingly the Helix SDK supports both MPEG-DASH (using MP4) and also HLSv4 to give a mix and match of supporting both competing HTTP streaming technologies or giving you a choice to migrate from HLS to MPEG-DASH using the same code. I have used this in development of Android apps in commercial services.

There are some slides on the web here which provides an insight 
http://www.slideshare.net/DavidJSmith2/helix-hls-and-mpegdash-sdk-for-android

and more details on the commercial site
http://www.realnetworks.com/helix/helix-sdk.aspx

Comment: thanks AndroidAppDev, But does this SDK support DASH for MPEG-2 TS format file play? Or is it only for MP4

Answer (score 5):

There is now http://www.dash-player.com, which supports Wowza MPDs out of the box, along with other MPDs. It comes with HTML5/JS, as well as a fallback to Adobe Flash. The basic version is free.

Comment: Is this a problem? "Added mpegdashStrictSpecComplianceForAST property for enabling strict spec compliance of the segment availability parameters provided in the live MPEG-DASH MPDs. Should not be enabled when using dash.js-based players such as the Wowza Streaming Engine Manager test DASH player." via [Wowza Streaming Engine 4.0.4 Release Notes](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?611)

Comment: This player is not based on dash.js and tested against the reference streams as well as Wowza streams, so there should be no problem. If you've problems with the player, please file an issue on the website.

Answer (score 3):

There are two more MPEG-DASH players worthy mentioned:

1. MP4Client as part of the GPAC project ([Here](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/))
2. Qt Player as part of libdash project ([Here](http://www.bitmovin.net/libdash/))

Both are opensource and have a supporting community.

IMO the GPAC project is better (the other one is pretty new) and I am currently using it for my own MPEG-DASH project.

BTW for the latest VLC Dash plugin you must compile from nighty sources.

Comment: True; thanks, I use MP4Client too. It chokes sometimes playing mpeg-2 TS files. Need to check with Qt player as you mentioned ..

Answer (score 1):

See [ExoPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) that support `HTTP (DASH)`, `SmoothStreaming`, and `persistent caching` for `Android 4.1` (API level 16) and superior.

Answer (score 0):

where did you get vlc dash plugin  I cant find it...I am unaware of any available mpeg dash player right now.  Supposedly there is a flash version but it is only a prototype and is not available

Comment: You can get VLC nightly build 2.1.0 onwards; It has built in working DASH support. You can go to Tools->Preferences->Show setting(All) There you will find a 'Stream filters'; where you can specify Resoultion and buffer size with which to play MPD file from network.

Answer (score 0):

There is the DASH-IF reference client which uses the Media Source Extensions to play natively in browsers.  Currently the only released browser with support is Chrome, but you can test streams in the latest player here.  http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/

You should be aware there are varying levels of support in the different chrome channe

Answer (score 0):

I created following MPD, but I am not able to play it on DASHIF JS player @ http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/

However same MPD, I was able to play via MP4Client/OSMO4 by GPAC

```
<MPD type="static" xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011" minBufferTime="PT10.5S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H2M31.63S">
<ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
<Title>Media Presentation Description for file flight_600.mp4 generated with GPAC    </Title>
</ProgramInformation>
<Period start="PT0S" duration="PT0H2M31.63S">
<AdaptationSet>
<ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video"/>
<SegmentTemplate initialization="flight_init.mp4"/>
<Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64000d" width="320"  height="180" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="589005">
<SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="1625" media="flight_test_flight_600$Number$.mp4" startNumber="1"/>
</Representation>
<Representation id="2" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001e" width="640" height="360" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="978740">
<SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="1625" media="flight_test_flight_1000$Number$.mp4" startNumber="1"/>
</Representation>
<Representation id="3" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001f" width="1280" height="720" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="2906174">
<SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="1625" media="flight_test_flight_3000$Number$.mp4" startNumber="1"/>
</Representation>
<Representation id="4" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.02" sampleRate="44100" numChannels="2" lang="und" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="122971">
<SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="1996" media="flight_test_flight_aud$Number$.mp4" startNumber="1"/>
</Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
</Period>
</MPD>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test player by wowza which supports MPEG-DASH

http://www.wowza.com/resources/3.6.0/examples/VideoOnDemandStreaming/MPEGDASHPlayer/player.html